# google linechart populated with database through asp.net using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I am a beginner in ASP.net I am trying to make a Google line chart using C# and JavaScript.

I got an error in my webpage like:

```
localhost says undefined:
```

Secondly, I also got an exception which I included in detail:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebApplication13.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How do I solve this error? Can it be resolved by adding zooming functionality. I want to make it responsive as when time change into nextdate and month and when I will zoom it will show last month records, etc.

My code is here:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication13.WebForm1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
         <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 10pt;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var options = {
                title: 'ipaddress',
                width: 600,
                height: 400,
                bar: { groupWidth: "95%" },
                legend: { position: "none" },
                isStacked: true
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetChartData",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);
                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($("#chart")[0]);
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                },
                failure: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                },
                error: function (r) {
                    alert(r.d);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">
    </div>
     
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**C# CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication13
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public static List<object> GetChartData()
        {
            string query = "SELECT [time],[average] FROM [dbo].[graph] WHERE ipaddress='192.168.15.167'";
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbsc"].ConnectionString;
            List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
            chartData.Add(new object[]
    {
        "time", "average"
    });
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            chartData.Add(new object[]
                    {
                        sdr["time"], sdr["average"]
                    });
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    return chartData;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check if your query return data, use `console.log(r)` before this line: `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(r.d);` and check the results in the console of your browser - press F12 > "Console" tab.